# Create multiply function SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I don't know if you can call it a multiply function, or function in function

[image]

I want to create output of productname number 5,6,7,8 from the small to the big one.
this output is from the big to the small

[image]

And i want to create the reverse output , create function that output the productname 5,6,7,8 asc 
and later create another function that output 5,6,7,8 order by price desc

How to do it ? thanks !

Comment: Whats your RDBMS...please mention it while asking question.

Comment: @anwaar_hell  Sorry !!! i'm new here ... 
SQL SERVER 2008

Comment: @Antonio..no need to sorry just giving you suggestion which i got few days back...:)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/33222878/73226

Comment: @MartinSmith someone deleted the answer. that given you something you post "duplicate ? "

Answer (score 0):

you just add column name desc order and limit to get number of record

```
 select * from products order by unitprice desc limit 5,4
```

Comment: you need to get records order by price desc ?

Comment: i need to get output of productname sorted from the small to big , but the trick here is to output only productname number 5,6,7,8

Comment: what u mean by 5,6,7,8

Comment: I mean if you select top 8 productname from products
order by unitprice asc
you get the output from smaller to the bigger . i want the output of top 8 but only 5,6,7,8 , without 1 ,2 ,3  4

Comment: ok then you should use limit at end of query , like (select * from products order by unitprice asc limit 5,4 ) limit 5,4 means get only 4 records start from record number 5 .. i edited my answer check it

Comment: My wrong. i have microsoft sql server 2012 and we do not have limit command.

Comment: SELECT TOP 5 * FROM (SELECT TOP 4 FROM products ORDER BY Id) ORDER BY Id DESC

Answer (score 0):

RowNumber() will fix your issue

[Row Number](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms186734.aspx)

```
WITH OrderedProducts AS
(
SELECT product_id, unit_price
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY unit_price DESC) AS RowNumber
)
SELECT product_id, unit_price
FROM OrderedProducts
WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN 4 AND 8;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to skip the first, second, third and fourth items, then you can use the NOT IN clause. Somewhat like this :

```
Select Top 8 product_id, price, other_fields etc from Table1 Where product_id not in (select Top 4 product_id from Table 1 where filter_goes_here Order By product_id asc) Order By Price desc
```